# How can we load js to a custom module created?

Tags: magento2, javascript

Can you please suggest us how to load js into the custom module created?
We are facing issues in loading the js to our custom module created

Comment: What is the issue? Can you post your code here?

Comment: You can refer: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-javascript-module/

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Create File in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <!--js file -->
       <script src="Vendor_Module::js/abcd.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then put **abcd.js** file inside App/Code/Vendor/Module/View/Frontend/web/js/

**Method 2:**

Add js using **requirejs-config.js** file

Create file app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customjs:'Vendor_Module/js/abcd'
        }
    }
};
```

And call in any template customjs script tag like as

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'customjs'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```